# Is it possible to change when didDetermineState of CLLocationManager is called?

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, core-location, ibeacon

When the beacon disappears, didDetermineState is called about 40 seconds later by default, but during that time didDetermineState is not called even if the beacon returns.
Therefore, we would like to call didDetermineState as soon as the beacon is lost and for didDetermineState to be called as soon as the beacon returns.

Here is didDetermineState.

```
 func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didDetermineState state: CLRegionState, for region: CLRegion) {
        switch (state) {
        case .inside:
            print("iBeacon inside")
            break;
        case .outside:
            print("iBeacon outside")
            break;
        case .unknown:
            print("iBeacon unknown")
            break;
        }
    }
```

I looked into it but could not find a way to change it.
I was hoping there was a method to change the time between the loss of the beacon and the call to didDetermineState, but could not find it.

Comment: `didDetermineState` *is called as soon as the beacon is lost* - as determined by the operating system.  Apple has built some hysteresis into the system to reduce the noise that would arise if a single missed packet was considered region exit.  There is no ability to change this behaviour.  You could use beacon ranging with a timer to react more quickly to a missed range update

Comment: Okay.
I had expected that it could not be done.
I give up.

Comment: Have you looked at beacon ranging?  That is the technique you would normally use for fine-grained monitoring of beacons once you know you are in the region.  Remember that beacon visibility isn't a binary yes/no situation - On the edge of the region you can expect the frequency of beacon frames to reduce until they finally go out of range